# Italian for concerto

Tags: terminology

I am watching an Italian TV series which prompted this question.

In English, concert and concerto are quite distinct.  The TV show made it apparent that the Italian concerto corresponds to English concert. So, what is Italian for English concerto?

Answer (score 1):

The English 'concerto' comes from the Italian 'concerto' which can mean both concert and concerto. There are other languages that use the same word for both e.g. German 'Konzert'.

Comment: It seems so but I expected that the sense might distinguished in some more subtle way.